# SQlite - Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, парсер, sqlite

Имеется код для парсинга сайта. Работает, в массив данные добавляет. Но при попытке переноса в базу SQlite выдает ошибку

```
> Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type."
```

Суть ошибки понимаю, пишет что не тот тип данных передаю, но вроде как у меня везде тип данных один - строка

Код парсера:

```py
import logging
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3
url = 'https://nekdo.ru/internet/'

HEADERS = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

def get_html(page):
    r = requests.get(url + page.__str__())
    return r


def add_text(html, page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    itArr = []
    for item1 in soup.select('.content .text'):
        try:
            tag = "Интернет"
            text = item1.get_text()
            itArr.append((tag, text))
        except:
            logging.error("Ошибка, тема - " + tag + ", Страница - " + page)
            print("Ошибка, тема - " + tag + ", Страница - " + page)
    print(itArr)
    return itArr, tag

def parser():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("anekdoty.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    PEGENATION = 2
    page = 1
    itArr=[]
    html = get_html(page)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        pass
        itArr=[]
        for page in range(1, PEGENATION+1):
            print(f"Парсим страницу: {page}")
            html = get_html(page)
            itArr.append(add_text(html.text, page))
            print(f"Закончили парсить страницу: {page}")
        print(f"Конец")
        print(itArr)
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO aneks VALUES (?,?)", itArr)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        print(f"Перенос в базу данных окончен")
        return itArr
    else:
        print("error")

parser()
```

Код для создания файла БД:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("anekdoty.db")
sql = "CREATE TABLE aneks(tag TEXT, text TEXT)"
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самом конце увидел что по итогу массив выходит странным, получается две ячейки, в левой все что вышло из функции add_text, в правой добавляется категория. Почему именно это происходит пока не понял `[([(' "массив из функции add_text" ')], 'Интернет')]`

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему создав изначально таблицу из кода самого парсера, а не из отдельного файла питон.
А вторую проблему решил заменив в def parser() append на extend